# IBM ERROR SQL0417N with EF6

Tags: linq, db2, entity-framework-6

**Using EntityFramework.IBM.DB2 (6.0.0) and :**

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24038828

**I created a Simple unit Test.**

```
using (var ctx = new ClaimHighLightsContext())   
   {           
    var c = "some valid string";           
     var result = ctx.ClaimTab.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CLM_CSR_CLAIM_NBR == c);          
     Assert.IsNotNull(result);     
   }
```

**Throw this Error:**

System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Exception:

> ERROR [42609] [IBM][DB2] SQL0417N  A statement string to be prepared
>   contains parameter markers as the operands of the same operator.

**But if I write this I get the expected result** :

```
using (var ctx = new ClaimHighLightsContext())
           {              
            var result = ctx.ClaimTab.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CLM_CSR_CLAIM_NBR == "some valid string");               
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
           }
```

**I'm using this package with:**

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="EntityFramework.IBM.DB2" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Any Help please

Comment: The error means that the `FirstOrDefault()` call translates to a SQL query that contains untyped parameter markers like `...WHERE ? = ?` and so DB2 cannot determine the data type to use in that comparison. I have no experience with Linq, but I'd suspect that the table to entity mapping for `ClaimTab` is incorrect or `CLM_CSR_CLAIM_NBR` is not a string.

Comment: The same entity mapping was working with Entity Framework 5 I just updated to Ef6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@juancarlos this can be resolved by setting `Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true` in your `DbContext` class.

If you need additional information you can take a look at the following discussion on codeplex as well as the MSDN documentation for the setting.

https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2115

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics(v=vs.113).aspx